# regular expression for not allowing white space at start

Tags: java, regex

A regular expression to allow only alphabets and numbers and spaces only in between alphabets with a maximum size of **20**.

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\\s][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*){0,20}`.

This does not allow white space at start, but it is not checking the max size condition. How can  I change this regular expression?

Comment: Would be good with a few examples of what it should match and what it shouldn't match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying 20 repetitions of the entire pattern. I am guessing you probably mean something like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][\\sa-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}
```

If empty input should be allowed, wrap the whole thing in `(...)?`.

Comment: Will this regular expression work for allowing empty string [a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1}[\\sa-zA-Z0-9]{0,19}

Comment: No, that is, it will allow empty input, but also removes the restriction that the first character has to be non-blank. Like I already explained in the answer, the way to do that is `([a-zA-Z0-9][\\sa-zA-Z0-9]{0,19})?`. The question mark is the more compact and idiomatic wsy to write `{0,1}`.

Answer (score 3):

All Sorts of ways to write this, and since you're using Java, why not use a Java regex "feature"? :D

```
String regexString = "(?<!\\s+)[\\w\\s&&[^_]]{0,20}";
```

Broken down, this says:

```
(?<!\\s+)  # not following one or more whitespace characters,
[          # match one of the following:
  \\w      # word character (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`)
  \\s      # whitespace characters
  &&[^_]   # EXCEPT FOR `_`
]          # 
{0,20}     # between 0 and 20 times
```

It will match `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and white space, even though the \w would otherwise include underscores, the extra part there says NOT underscores - I think it's unique to Java... anyways, that was fun!

Answer (score 0):

The regex below :

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("(?i)^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:\\s[a-z0-9]+)*$");
```

will match a string of 1 to 20 characters starting with an alphanumeric character followed by a single space and more alphanumeric characters. Note that the string must end with an alphanumeric character and not a space.